# Android: Layout used by wechat

Tags: android, android-layout, wechat

In WeChat, it uses white sections for different things as you can see in below image there are three white sections in it and each item is separated by a black line:

[image]

I can suspect this is not a **ListView** as one might think in first glance.

Question: Does anyone know is this some built-in component that can be used or how to go about creating similar sections ?

Comment: This screenshot would appear to be from an iOS device. iOS devices do not run Android. They run iOS. More importantly, iOS does not have Android's `ListView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Sorry updated the image.

Comment: could be a preferencesfragment

Comment: You can make this using a listview?

Comment: Next, use **`uiautomatorviewer`** and see what widgets and container they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a linearlayout inside a scrollview with your custom listview and custom adapter is the most straightforward solution.

Each time the view is inflated you check the shared preference and fill in the info accordingly in your adapter. And on item click you open corresponding fragment/activity that do something. Then you issue a callback to refresh this settings view.

Might not be the most elegant way to do it. But I think this one is easy and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its a preferences activity/fragment but you can create it with a listview, linearlayouts or a combination of a scrollview and a linearlayout. 
You have too many solutions ;)